# How to pass data and datastring?

Tags: jquery

How can I pass variable similar_id with datastring ? Seperatly.

```
var id=$(this).attr("id");       
var name=$(this).attr("name");       
var similar_id=$(this).attr("similar_id");    
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name='+ name;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "conf.php",
data: dataString,         <---
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use data *object* instead of string.

This will help to overcome many problems with passing and encoding parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "conf.php",
    data: {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        similar_id: similar_id
    },
    cache: false,
    ...
});
```